# Hibernate - Could not resolve property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have table Users which contains column `iduser` (long) fk -> to table login to column `id_user` (long).

But I don't want to map table login into users. I just want to use this column `iduser` in Users like normal column and find specific object.

When I wrote something like this:

```
...
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(ID_USER, (long) 3);
...
```

The error will appear:

> could not resolve property: iduser of: model.domain.User

But when I used standard `SQLQuery`:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from Users where iduser = 3");
List list = query.list();
```

it will found the specific object.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: How it is mapped in hbm/pojo? Can you post your pojo file. Hibernate uses pojo attributes as column names, so try to use attribute that is mapped to iduser.

Comment: i use annotations:

User.java

@Column(updatable = false, name = "iduser", nullable = false)
private long idUser;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names of the persistent attributes are case sensitive. Because name of the attribute is `idUser`, it is expected that attribute `iduser` (lower case 'u') cannot be found. When Criteria or HQL is used, it is names of the attributes, not the names of the database columns that matters.